# Using a variable in mysql regexp search

Tags: php, mysql

I actually want to search the hashtags with this MySQL query.But its not working for me, I don't know why.

Here is my code. My code uses a PHP variable inside

```
$searchtext = "#truth";

"SELECT id FROM bp_activity WHERE content REGEXP '[[:<:]]'". $searchtext ."'[[:>:]]'"
```

This is returning empty but one of the rows in the table contains this expression like this:

```
Unveilling the <a href="?hashtag=truth&amp;s=truth">#truth</a>
```

I think it should be sorted out.

But when I only use this this it works

```
"SELECT id FROM bp_activity WHERE content REGEXP '[[:<:]]truth[[:>:]]'"
```

But it `doesn't` work when using like this

```
"SELECT id FROM bp_activity WHERE content REGEXP '[[:<:]]#truth[[:>:]]'"
```

Comment: `'[[:<:]]'` means word boundary, is it? but `'#'` is a symbol which is not treated as in-word one, so the word boundary in the value is posessed between `'#'` and `'t'`.

Comment: @Akina but what sould i do now?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`?

Comment: *what sould i do now?* Remove left word boundary from the pattern, use `REGEXP '". $searchtext ."[[:>:]]'"` only (`REGEXP '#truth[[:>:]]'`).